Movie about a boys orphanage
About 12 years ago, I was watching Television and came by a movie about a boys orphanage (or I think it was one) ruled by some religious order in a war environment. Because it was so long ago, the details I will provide maybe inaccurate but I'll do my best to.
Movie specs:

Language: English (I think it had a british accent but I'm not sure)
Photography: It was in colours (a little bit desaturated and mid-dark)
Time: Something near World War II or before that
When it was made: probably the 90's

The thing that I remember the most is that the place was like a monastery, and there were a lot o boys in a young age that were in some way exploited to do some daily tasks.
The scene that is more present in me is this one with the main character (that is one of the boys) that is in charge of bringing everyday the main meals of one of the high entitled persons. The boys were in very poor conditions and went through a lot of hunger.
The boy in charge of the meals would hide in the stairs in the way to the room where the old man was laying, only to lick the sausages to feel the taste of real food. One day, the boy reaches the room and the old man is dead, the boy becomes scared and starts running throw the door but than looks to the plate of food on top of the table and decides to have his ever first meal before warning the supervisors and pretend that the old man died after he ate.
UPDATE:
Found it: https://ifiarchiveplayer.ie/the-breakfast/

Possibly the Irish short film The Breakfast from 1998. From an online description:

a boy at a Catholic boarding school brings breakfast every day to the priest who is his school supervisor. "Every morning, he licks the sausages just enough to get a taste, then goes back and eats his gruel," recounts Kleeman. One day, the boy delivers the breakfast, only to find the priest dead. His reaction? He happily eats the sausage-and-egg breakfast.

It was written an directed by playwright Peter Sheridan.
